# Refer sqlContext as global variable

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, databricks

I created an object as below :

```
class Pivot:

    def __init__(self, pivot_name):

        global sqlContext
        self._df = sqlContext.table(pivot_name)
```

In Databricks, I packaged this code in a .egg, attached it to my cluster, then, from a notebook (where `sqlContext` is defined directly), I tried:

```
import Pivot

Pivot("my_pivot")
```

and got error `name 'sqlContext' is not defined`

Is there a way my .egg package can see directly the object `sqlContext` or I need absolutely to pass it as an argument ?